# Prove that polynomial $p(x)$ does not have integer roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I'm trying to solve this task:

> $P(x)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients. For some natural number $c$, c does not divide $P(1), ..., P(c)$. Prove that $P(X)$ does not have integer roots.

My observations:

if $P(c) = a_1c^n+a_2c^{n-1}+...+a_{n-1}c+a_n$ is not divisible by $c$ so must be $a_n$. Also $P(0) = a_n$ so we can say that c does not divide $P(0)$.

None of values $P(0), P(1), ..., P(c)$ can equal to zero since c will divide zero.

Then $P(c) = a_1c^n+a_2c^{n-1}+...+a_{n-1}c+a_n = a_1c^n+a_2c^{n-1}+...+a_{n-1}c+P(0)$

and we know that $c$ does not divide $P(c)$ and also $P(0)$ so this sum

$a_1c^n+a_2c^{n-1}+...+a_{n-1}c $

should not be divisible by $c$ but it is. So there seems to be a contradiction.

Is this approach correct? I am not sure how it shows that $P(x)$ does not have integer roots.

Could somebody please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don’t have a good hint but your approach is incorrect. Note that $2$ does not divide $3$ nor $1$ but $2$ divides $3-1$ so there is no contradiction at the end of your argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the argument that if $a\nmid (b+c)$ and $a\nmid c$ then $a\nmid b$ which is evidently not true. Because $2\nmid (2+3)$ and $2\nmid 3$. But $2$ divides 2.

Proper argument might go like this. I am avoiding the use of congruences which I feel you might be unaware of:

Suppose for some integer $m$, we have $p(m)=0$. Then, as you noted $c$ divides $p(m)$. Now, consider the integers $m-1, m-2, \dots, m-c$. One of these numbers must be divisible by $c$, say it is $m-r$, $1\leq r \leq c$.

It can now be shown that $c$ divides $p(r)$. This is easy to see. Simply consider:
$$ p(m)-p(r) = a_n(m^n-r^n)+a_{n-1}(m^{n-1}-r^{m-1})+\dots+ a_1(m-r),$$
where $p(x) = a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_1x+a_0$.

Clearly
$$p(m)-p(r) = (m-r) C,$$
for some integer $C$ (This is because $m^k-r^k = (m-r)\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1} m^ir^{k-1-i}$. Hence we can take $(m-r)$ common throughout).

Since $c$ divides $m-r$, $ c$ must divide $p(m)-p(r)$ and hence it must divide $p(r)$ as it divides $p(m)$. This is a contradiction as $1\leq r \leq c$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice: $P(qc+k) \equiv P(k) (\text{mod } c)$.

This is because the only term that won't contain $c$ in the expansion of $a_{i}(qc+k)^{i}$ is $a_{i}k^{i}$.

Now suppose $a$ is some root of $P(x)$. Then $P(a)=0$. Now write $a=qc + r$, with $0\leq r<c$. Clearly, $0 = P(a) = P(qc+r) \equiv P(r) ( \text{mod }c)$
Meaning, $P(r) \equiv 0( \text{mod } c)$. But we know $0\leq r <c$, meaning $c$ can't divide $P(r)$, meaning we have reached an contradiction. So no such root can exist.

**Edit:**
$r=0$ is a non issue, since $P(0)=a_{0}$ has already been proven to not be divisible by $c$ by the OP. My mistake for forgetting this was not included in the problem statement.

Comment: How contradiction arose? What if $r=0$? One more step is missing in your proof.

Comment: OP has already proven $P(0) = a_{0}$ is not divisible by $c$

Comment: Sorry that I just overlooked. Your previous answer was fine.

Answer (score 1):

We suppose that $P$ has a root integer $\alpha$. Let $r$ be the remainder of the euclidean division of $\alpha$ through $c$, then $c \mid \alpha - r$, but we know that $\alpha - r \mid P(r)-P(\alpha)$, since $P(\alpha)=0$ we have $\alpha - r \mid P(r)$. Thus $c \mid P(r)$, recall that $r \in \{0,1,\ldots,c-1\}$ which is a contradiction with the fact:

> $c$ does not divide $P(0),P(1), \ldots,P(c)$